# how multiprocess.Pool and classmethod work in unittest with python3.4

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.3, python-unittest, python-3.4

I'm trying to write unittest for a Lock object, like this

```
import time
import unittest
from multiprocessing import Pool


class LockTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def f(self, x):
        time.sleep(1)

    def test_lock(self):
        p = Pool(2)
        p.map(self.f, (1, 1, 1))

unittest.main()
```

let's keep `f` in TestCase class, it works with python3.3, but when work with python3.4, it comes out

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
  return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
  raise self._value
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 383, in _handle_tasks
  put(task)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
  self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
  cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

so, how classmethod `f` in Pool works in python3.4 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution is define function 'f' outside LockTestCase. Maybe it is simplest. But you function 'f' anyway running only 'map' method.